# Do mutants who have mind powers have their power as a part of their atomic structure the same way mutants with physical powers, or not?

Tags: marvel, x-men, mutant, powers

When a mutant in X-men gets powers does it affect their atomic structure whether their powers are physical or not, I am curious to know?

A mutant with any form of power that isn't directly physical, like controlling gravity or someone's mind, is this a part of their atomic structure or is it a part of maybe their subconscious or "spirit"?

I.e. a power commonly known like superhuman strength alters their atomic being because it alters their physical capabilities, but someone who can control someone's mind, does that work the same way?

Comment: I believe all mutant powers are DNA-based, so certainly the “atomic structure” of any mutant is altered in that sense. Of course, the soul is certainly a thing in Marvel (comics anyway), and some mutants with mental abilities have been able to survive in bodyless form, so.... Perhaps a DNA mutation, but one that alters their spiritual form somehow as well?

Comment: I've seen times when a Marvel mutant got his or her mind transferred into someone else's body. As a general rule, this means the superpowers *don't* go along for the ride. The character only has whatever superpowers this other body *already possessed* (if any). So I don't think the powers tend to be "part of the spirit" that got transferred from Body A to Body B. (But I wouldn't be surprised if there have been exceptions, somewhere along the line -- so many stories, so many writers, anything could happen!)

Comment: yeah I like your interpretation
I just couldnt decide whether someone who could like control pressure or the mind or some other form of psionic power like telekineses would have that engraved in their dna and such if someone with the power to mimic someone's atomic structure perfectly came across them whether they could obtain their powers because itd depend whether their psionic powers derive from a spiritual part of their-self or whether it was part of their engraved dna?

Answer (score 1):

In the Marvel Universe, not explicitly. For example, we don't see the X-Men running around with bags of spare Wolverine or Deadpool blood for its healing effects (although technically they could harvest organs from them). It has been done elsewhere - *Heroes* allowed Claire's blood to be used as healing factors for others, and *DC*'s Deathstroke & Midnighter can share their blood to give healing for brief periods of time.

Likewise, we commonly see psychic characters either not needing their physical bodies or losing their powers without harm to those bodies. Jean Grey in the Phoenix Saga (comics) has those powers psychically removed, while in the much-maligned X-Men Last Stand movie, Professor X can inhabit the body of his brain-dead twin brother after his body's death.

But the main thing that proves it wrong is the House of M/Decimation Storyline. Here, the Scarlet Witch removed the Mutations by altering reality with "no more mutants" (save about 200) and removing the "X-gene" from them. However, this did not always remove ALL of the effects of the mutation, leaving some depowered mutants still *looking like* mutants even though their biological cause for that mutation was gone.